# Dynamic performance % dax formula

Tags: dynamic, powerbi, dax

Hope you all are doing well and safe!!

I have a question regarding Power BI dax. I want to create a dax measure for performance percentage in which numerator and denominator will be as per user filter.

**Case 1:** I want to create a dax measure for performance % **(Current Month Sales / Dec'20 Sales)** in which current month value will be depending upon user drop down filter and denominator will be fixed with Dec'20 sales value.

**Case 2:** I want to create a dax measure for performance % **(Current Month Sales / Previous Month Sales)** in which current month value will be depending upon user drop down filter and denominator will be as per previous month depending upon month selection done by user.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Try these measures

```
Case 1 =
DIVIDE (
    [Measure],
    CALCULATE (
        [Measure],
        Dates[Calendar Year Number] = 2020,
        Dates[Month Number] = 12,
        REMOVEFILTERS ( Dates )
    )
)
```

```
Case 2 =
VAR SelectedMonth =
    CALCULATE ( MAX ( Dates[Calendar Year Month Number] ), ALLSELECTED ( Dates ) )
VAR PreviousMonth =
    CALCULATE (
        MAX ( Dates[Calendar Year Month Number] ),
        Dates[Calendar Year Month Number] < SelectedMonth,
        REMOVEFILTERS ( Dates )
    )
VAR Result =
    DIVIDE (
        [Measure],
        CALCULATE (
            [Measure],
            Dates[Calendar Year Month Number] = PreviousMonth,
            REMOVEFILTERS ( Dates )
        )
    )
RETURN
    Result
```